# Flutter decrease space between checkbox and it's title

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am using CheckboxListTile in this way:

```
ListTileTheme(
  contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 20.0),
  child: CheckboxListTile(
    controlAffinity: ListTileControlAffinity.leading,
    value: false,
    onChanged: (value) {},
    title: Text(
      "افزودن به فهرست پرکاربردها"
    ),
  ),
),
```

and it's result :

[image]

How can I decrease space between checkbox and it's title?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In `CheckBoxListTile`, it is probably difficult to achieve what you want. However, there is always a workaround for that, and this is using `Row()`. Also, we will using `FlatButton()` to get the same effect.

The catch here is, in `FlatButton()`, you just have to do the same thing as `onChanged` in `Checkbox()`

### Solution

```
     bool _myBool = false;

     Container(
        child: FlatButton(
          // here toggle the bool value so that when you click 
          // on the whole item, it will reflect changes in Checkbox
          onPressed: () => setState(() => _myBool = !_myBool),
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              SizedBox(
                height: 24.0,
                width: 24.0,
                child: Checkbox(
                  value: _myBool,
                  onChanged: (value){
                     setState(() => _myBool = value);
                  }
                )
              ),
              // You can play with the width to adjust your
              // desired spacing
              SizedBox(width: 10.0),
              Text("افزودن به فهرست پرکاربردها")
            ]
          )
        )
      )
```

### Result

[image: RESULTANT IMAGE]

And if you want the `Checkbox()` to be at the right, you can just switch the places of `Text()` and `Checkbox()`. Rest will remain the same.

Answer (score 29):

use Transform.translate

```
Transform.translate(
                          offset: const Offset(-20, 0),
                         child: childWidget(),
)
```

Complete Example

```
Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0),
                      child: CheckboxListTile(
                        value: isChecked,
                        controlAffinity: ListTileControlAffinity.leading,
                        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                        title: Transform.translate(
                          offset: const Offset(-20, 0),
                          child: RichText(
                            text: TextSpan(
                              text: S.of(context).iAgreeWith,
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Theme.of(context).hintColor,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w400),
                              children: <TextSpan>[
                                TextSpan(
                                  text: S.of(context).terms,
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      decoration: TextDecoration.underline,
                                      color: Theme.of(context).hintColor,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w400),
                                  recognizer: TapGestureRecognizer()
                                    ..onTap = () {
                                      // Single tapped.

                                      Navigator.push(
                                          context,
                                          MaterialPageRoute(
                                            builder: (context) => WebView(
                                              url:
                                                  ksportsCornerWebsitePolicyUrl,
                                              title: S.of(context).termsCap,
                                            ),
                                          ));
                                    },
                                ),
                                TextSpan(
                                    text: " " + S.of(context).and + " ",
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                        color: Theme.of(context).hintColor,
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w400)),
                                TextSpan(
                                  text: S.of(context).privacyPolicy,
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      decoration: TextDecoration.underline,
                                      color: Theme.of(context).hintColor,
                                      //fontSize: 14.0.sp,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w400),
                                  recognizer: TapGestureRecognizer()
                                    ..onTap = () {
                                      // Single tapped.

                                      Navigator.push(
                                          context,
                                          MaterialPageRoute(
                                            builder: (context) => WebView(
                                              url:
                                                  ksportsCornerWebsitePolicyUrl,
                                              title: S
                                                  .of(context)
                                                  .privacyPolicyCaps,
                                            ),
                                          ));
                                    },
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        activeColor: Theme.of(context).hintColor,
                        checkColor: Theme.of(context).cursorColor,
                        onChanged: (value) {
                          isChecked = !isChecked;
                          setState(() {});
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
```

[image]

Comment: What an answer! Thank you @saif! Beautiful

Answer (score 11):

Add `horizontalTitleGap: 0,` to ListTileTheme.

```
ListTileTheme(
  horizontalTitleGap: 0,
  child: CheckboxListTile(
    controlAffinity: ListTileControlAffinity.leading,
    value: false,
    onChanged: (value) {},
    title: Text(
      "افزودن به فهرست پرکاربردها"
    ),
  ),
),
```

Before :

[image]

After:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This helped me
Add this inside ListTileTheme
horizontalTitleGap: 0,

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing the ListTileTheme with this:

```
Padding(
  padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 20.0),
  child: Row(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
    children: <Widget>[
      Text(
        "افزودن به فهرست پرکاربردها"
      ),
      SizedBox(
        width: /* The spacing in between the checkbox and text */ 20,
      ),
      Checkbox(
        value: false,
        onChanged: (value) {},
      ),
    ],
  ),
),
```

Comment: I know that it is possible to do this with Row() but I want to use `CheckboxListTile` bro

Comment: I don't think there is a way to decrease the spacing of the checkbox listTile. Using a Row is the only way to do it. You can read [the docs for the checkbox  listTile](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/CheckboxListTile-class.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your title text widget with Align one like the example of code below:

```
              ListTileTheme(
                  contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 20.0),
                  child: CheckboxListTile(
                    controlAffinity: ListTileControlAffinity.leading,
                    value: false,
                    onChanged: (value) {},
                    title: const Align(
                      alignment: Alignment(-13, 0),
                      child: Text("افزودن به فهرست پرکاربردها"),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
```